# Problem drawing a rectangle in Godot fragment shader

Tags: fragment-shader, godot

I'm having a fragment shader that draw some stuff. On top of that I want it to draw 1-pixel thick rectangle around the fragment. I have using step function, but the problem is the UV coordinates that is between 0.0 -1.0. How do I know when the fragment is at a specific pixel? For this I want to draw on the edges.

`c.r  = step(0.99, UV.x);
c.r += step(0.99, 1.0-UV.x);
c.r += step(0.99, UV.y);
c.r += step(0.99, 1.0-UV.y);`

The code above just draw a rectangle, but the problem thicknes is 0.01% of total width/hight.
Is there any good description of UX, FRAGCOORD, SCREEN_TEXTURE and SCREEN_UV?

Comment: I'm not enough of a shader guru to answer your question, but the fragment built-ins are documented [here](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/tutorials/shading/shading_reference/spatial_shader.html#fragment-built-ins)

Comment: @rcorre Unfortunately, it doesn’t provide any detailed explanation.

Comment: Typically in shaders you don't try to draw specific pixels, you modulate the brightness of each pixel depending on the distance to the feature you're trying to draw

Answer (score 2):

If it is good enough for you to work in screen coordinates (i.e., you want to define position and thickness in terms of screen space) you can use `FRAGCOORD`. It corresponds to the `(x, y)` pixel coordinates within the viewport, i.e., with the default viewport of 1024 x 600, the lower left pixel would be (0, 0), and the top right would be (1024, 600).

If you want to map the fragment coordinates back to world space (i.e., you want to define position and thickness in terms of world space), you must follow the [work-around mentioned here](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/19800).